# VScode - java.io.FileNotFoundException: (the system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, file-io, filenotfoundexception, invocationtargetexception

I have project with a JSON file "`userData.json`".

The file is in the same directory as my `java` files.

I moved the file directly under the project root folder and it did not fix the problem:

```
Project_Root
    src
    userData.json
```

Code of the java file that attempts to open userData.json:

```
private boolean checkData(String username, String password) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //read userData.json
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(new FileReader("group18/src/main/java/com/example/group18/userData.json")));
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users1");

    //loop through the json array and compare the username and password
    if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("username").equals(username) && jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("password").equals(password)){
        jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).put("online", true);
        //return true if the username and password are correct
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reading userData.json with the above project structure

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(new FileReader("userData.json")));
```

Comment: Did not change the FileNotFoundException